# Kivy/KivyMD is there a way to turn of the click animation you get on an object

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

If you click on a button or list item etc you get a animation on your button. This is actually very nice in most cases but when you work on a black(ish) background its not nice. Does anyone know if there is a way to turn it off?

[image: 1]

Comment: Set `ripple_alpha` to 0.

Comment: Been searching for this since days now. Thank you kind sir!